# Load EFI file from foreign volume with systemd-boot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, boot-loader, systemd-boot

I have two efi partitions on two different drives (one for windows, one for the rest). I'm aware that it normally should be unified, but there may be some applications where you'd want to preserve another install and boot it:

I have to boot loaders registered, but selecting them at bios level every time is a bit cumbersome and requires manual interaction (and takes longer):

```
Boot Loaders Listed in EFI Variables:
        Title: UEFI OS
           ID: 0x0019
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/[linuxefi]
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI

    Title: Windows Boot Manager
       ID: 0x0001
   Status: active, boot-order
Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/[winefi]
     File: └─/EFI/MICROSOFT/BOOT/BOOTMGFW.EFI
```

`UEFI OS` is the systemd-boot loader. I use it by default. I just need to add an entry for the efi file on the `winefi` partition.

There is documentation for [loading other efi shells/apps](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot#EFI_Shells_or_other_EFI_apps), however, I'm not sure if it can be done on another disk:

`/boot/loader/entries/windows.conf`:

```
title   Windows
partition/volume PARTUUID=[winefi] !?
efi /EFI/MICROSOFT/BOOT/BOOTMGFW.EFI
```

`RefInd` seems to have a `volume` token to specify where the subsequent files reside. I wonder if systemd-boot has something compareable.

Comment: See example in post #5 https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=214239 And your partUUID or GUID (in UEFI) can be seen: `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"`

Comment: @oldfred I wrote `[winefi]` and `[linuxefi]` in lieu of the actual UUIDs. I thought that was obvious. I already found and read that thread. It doesn't help me as they only suggest using the preboot menu. There is no info on how to load an efi app from another volume. Perhaps it just isn't possible with systemd-boot.

Comment: Since GUID & UUIDs are different for another ESP, I do not see why that is not the way to load from another ESP.

Comment: It definitely is A way, but e.g. you can't programmatically reboot a an os of your choice that way. And you have to bring up the menu every time. It is possible to load from another volume (with another uuid and guid) with refind, I'm just wondering if it can be done with systemd boot. But so far, it looks like it's hardwired to the specified ESP.